# Is there something in Memgraph that has the same function as APOC in Neo4j?

Tags: memgraphdb

I know that both Memgraph and Neo4j use Cypher as query language. I see that Neo4j has APOC (Awesome Procedures on Cypher). Is there a Memgraph version or replacement for APOC?

I've looked at Memgraph documentation but I couldn't find info on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

APOC is a custom Neo4j library of stored procedures and functions that depends on Java runtime/API.

Memgraph doesn’t have Java runtime (it will probably never have) so it’s not possible to run APOC procedures; hence there is nothing in the docs.

But there are a few ways to use/approach Memgraph:

- Similar to APOC, Memgraph provides a set of the shelf modules/functions called [MAGE](https://github.com/memgraph/mage) (Memgraph Advanced Graph Extensions), you can write your own query modules by using MAGE.
- There is also a C API, which allows users to write extensions for Memgraph in any programming language, so far Memgraph have a native API for [C/C++/Python/Rust](https://memgraph.com/docs/memgraph/connect-to-memgraph/drivers) so that any developer feels like at home because these native APIs are all specific for a given language and ecosystem.
- Memgraph has Python runtime embedded, which allows users to easily integrate Memgraph and any library from the vast Python ecosystem; NetworkX,  Pytorch, Pandas just to name a few.